# Conditional logic in Markdown or other simple markup language?

Tags: documentation, markdown, documentation-generation

Im looking for an implementation of a Markdown-like language that will allow me to embed "conditional logic" within my document.

I imagine the document would look something like:

```
This text should be included in all processed versions of the document

[platform==foo]
This is an example for platform Foo

[platform==bar]
This is an example for platform Bar
```

Then different versions of the document could be produced by passing parameters to the processing script:

```
./process-markdown --platform=foo
```

My Googling hasn't returned anything close to this, though I feel like something like this must exist for software documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue today and found another interesting approach here using markdown and gpp: https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/markdown-with-gpp/

Answer (score 1):

[AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/index.html) has [Conditional Inclusion Macros](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#_system_macros).

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) also can be used as a Markup-language and have [\if, \endif etc.](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdif) commands.

For Markdown it's maybe easier you write your own simple regex-filter-script.